# Check if variable is different, Echo out and then update variable to recheck

Tags: php, while-loop

I have the code, but i do not know if the logic is off.
Its a listener on a Socket and i know i am i should be getting 3/4 different responses
but i am only getting 1/2 responses. I believe my logic is wrong.

Want the code to loop through and only print out when the response is different from the first response.
(i.e. i do not want a log file cluttered with the same responses, only when its different)

Here is my code:

```
$connecProgress = fsockopen($IPAddress, $portStatus, $errno, $errstr, 5);
$response = fgets($connecProgress);
while (true) {
    $datetime = date("d-m-Y h:i:s");
    if (fgets($connecProgress ) != $response)
    {
        echo $datetime."  Status: " .  fgets($connecProgress) ."<br>";
        $response = fgets($connecProgress);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

i know there is no break in this loop, it will be added at a later date when i have confirmed all the logs are printed. It just needs to be an indefinite listener at the moment

**Update 1**

Based on El_Vanja comment

```
$connecProgress = fsockopen($IPAddress, $portStatus, $errno, $errstr, 5);
$response = fgets($connecProgress);
while (true) {
    $datetime = date("d-m-Y h:i:s");
    echo $datetime."  Status: " . $response ."<br>";
    $newResponse = fgets($connecProgress);
    if ($newResponse != $response)
    {
        echo $datetime."  Status: " . $newResponse ."<br>";
        $response = fgets($connecProgress);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: You get a line twice in your loop, first in the `if`, then in the `echo`. Shouldn't you store it to use the same entry in one iteration?

Comment: IF - Compares Variable to fget (Response from Socket) If its different then move into the Statement. 
Then to Echo out the response. 
Then to Set the Variable with the updated response from the socket. So it can loop through again and check if its different.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are making a new fetch each time you call the command. Imagine that responses are `1, 2, 3, 4`. When you call `fgets($connecProgress);` before the loop, it gets `1`. Then you call it in the `if` and it gets `2`. Then in echo it gets `3` and finally, when you store it in `$response` again, it gets `4`. My point was you should store it at the beginning of the loop (`$newResponse = fgets($connecProgress)`) and then use that variable for the rest of the loop operations instead of calling `fgets` again. Clearer?

Comment: Updated based on your comment, Yes makes sense what you are saying, Believe I've updated it according to your feedback

Comment: I believe you should do `$response = $newResponse;` instead of `$response = fgets($connecProgress);` inside the loop as well. Otherwise you're once again skipping one step ahead.